# Simple ajax request to save variable to django backend from template

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have score field in UserProfile model. And variable total in jquery.
I want to store value of total in score field after clicking on submit button.
I want to make ajax call for that.

here i tried some thing.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    var bjpFan=localStorage['bjpFan'];
    var total = parseInt(localStorage['total']);
    $.ajax({
      url: "/poll/score/",
      type:"GET",
      success: function(responseHTML){
       {% for sc in score1 %}
           var s={{sc.score}}
           alert(s);
       {% endfor %}
      }
    });
});
```

Now i want to save value in backend. How to save that single value.

view.py

```
def score(request):
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        score1=UserProfile.objects.all()
        print "akash"
        print score1
        print type(score1)
        response = json.dumps({"SCORE":score})
        return HttpResponse(response,mimetype="application/json")
```

model.py is

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    score = models.IntegerField(max_length = 50, blank = True,null = True)
```

want to store total to score,,,, but total is a variable declared in jquery

Comment: your query is not explain your working can you give us more detail of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way:

your html:

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  var bjpFan=localStorage['bjpFan'];
  var userid = //get your user id in some way you can
  var total = parseInt(localStorage['total']);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/poll/score/",
    type:"GET",
    data: {total:total,userid:userid}
  }).done(function(data){
     alert(data);//do what you want to do with response
  });
});
```

your urls.py:

```
url(r'/poll/score/$', 'score', name='score'),
```

your views.py

```
def score(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
     if request.method == 'GET':
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('userid'))
        user.score = request.GET.get('total')
        user.save()
        return HttpResponse("%s" % user.score )
```

thats it.

Comment: Thanks a lot,,,,,,,,,, one again,,,,,,,,
can i ask you a simple question?
Can we customize the admin view?
want name, Score in one row like users,, it has username Email address, first name, last name on same page list wise. Like that.

Comment: @GauravWagh sure, this is possible. take a look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/